# rcases with parbox to fit residual space

Tags: boxes, cases

I have the following construct (using package `mathtools`)

```
\begin{drcases}
    Content....
\end{drcases} \parbox{.53\textwidth}{Long Multiline Text Blablabla}
```

I am using `cases` to display some long text and I found out that by putting the text into a `\parbox` I can spread it across mutliple lines. But I ended up with manually adjusting the text width (`.53\textwidth`)

And because I have this kind of construct multiple times in my document, I was wondering if it is not possible to automatically calculate the text width, so that I don't need to do this each time by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An application of `xparse` (see edit history for versions of `xparse` prior to 2019-03-05)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{xdrcases}{O{4em}mb}
 {
  \axmx_xdrcases:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
 {}

\box_new:N \l_axmx_xdrcases_box
\dim_new:N \l_axmx_xdrcases_dim

\cs_new_protected:Npn \axmx_xdrcases:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_axmx_xdrcases_box
   {
    $\begin{drcases}#3\end{drcases}$
   }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_axmx_xdrcases_dim
   {
    \displaywidth - \box_wd:N \l_axmx_xdrcases_box - #1
   }
  \box_use:N \l_axmx_xdrcases_box
  \quad
  \parbox{\l_axmx_xdrcases_dim}{#2}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{1.1.\arabic{equation}} % just to show the problem

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation*}
\begin{xdrcases}{
  Some long descriptive text, very boring indeed, but
  that should be long enough to require splitting it
  across lines
}
\frac{1}{2}x  & \text{if $x$ is rational} \\
-x & \text{if $x$ is irrational}
\end{xdrcases}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}
\begin{xdrcases}[6em]{
  Some long descriptive text, very boring indeed, but
  that should be long enough to require splitting it
  across lines
}
\frac{1}{2}x  & \text{if $x$ is rational} \\
-x & \text{if $x$ is irrational}
\end{xdrcases}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

The optional argument (default 4em) sets the space to be left empty; as you see, in case of long equation numbers 4em can be too small, so one can act consequently.

[image]

You might want to examine the following variant, where the text to be put on the side comes after the `\sidecondition` macro; if `\sidecondition` doesn't appear, the environment is the same as `drcases`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{xdrcases}{O{4em}b}
 {
  \axmx_xdrcases:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
 {}

\box_new:N \l_axmx_xdrcases_box
\dim_new:N \l_axmx_xdrcases_dim
\seq_new:N \l_axmx_xdrcases_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \axmx_xdrcases:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_axmx_xdrcases_seq { \sidecondition } { #2 }
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l_axmx_xdrcases_seq > 1 }
   {% there is a side condition
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_axmx_xdrcases_box
     {
      $\begin{drcases}\seq_item:Nn \l_axmx_xdrcases_seq { 1 }\end{drcases}$
     }
    \dim_set:Nn \l_axmx_xdrcases_dim
     {
      \displaywidth - \box_wd:N \l_axmx_xdrcases_box - #1
     }
    \box_use:N \l_axmx_xdrcases_box
    \quad
    \parbox{\l_axmx_xdrcases_dim}{\seq_item:Nn \l_axmx_xdrcases_seq { 2 }}
   }
   {% no side condition
    \begin{drcases}#2\end{drcases}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{1.1.\arabic{equation}} % just to show the problem

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation*}
\begin{xdrcases}
  \frac{1}{2}x  & \text{if $x$ is rational} \\
  -x & \text{if $x$ is irrational}
\sidecondition
  Some long descriptive text, very boring indeed, but
  that should be long enough to require splitting it
  across lines
\end{xdrcases}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}
\begin{xdrcases}[6em]
  \frac{1}{2}x  & \text{if $x$ is rational} \\
  -x & \text{if $x$ is irrational}
\sidecondition
  Some long descriptive text, very boring indeed, but
  that should be long enough to require splitting it
  across lines
\end{xdrcases}
\end{equation}
\lipsum*[4]
\begin{equation*}
\begin{xdrcases}
  \frac{1}{2}x  & \text{if $x$ is rational} \\
  -x & \text{if $x$ is irrational}
\end{xdrcases}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ax1mx2 Wait a few hours and perhaps an even better version will arrive.

Comment: I am so happy that one worked out so well, though it doesn't seem like much of an elegant solution to a newbee like me.